# JQuery code to long tap for long term event

Tags: jquery

Im trying to fire an event of "long tap", so if the user wont raise his finger of the mouse the code will continue adding `"yay!"`  forever:

this is my code :

```
var pressTimer

            $("#area").mouseup(function () {
                clearTimeout(pressTimer)
                // Clear timeout
                return false;
            }).mousedown(function(){
                // Set timeout
                pressTimer = window.setTimeout(function () {
                    $('#result').html('yay!');
                }, 1000)
                return false; 
            });
```

so far, its only firing it once, and then stops.
what can I do to make it happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setInterval instead of setTimeout, and you need to append to the text of your result div instead of replacing it's content.  There are multiple ways to append, but I just did a string concat in the example.
http://jsfiddle.net/7E7Jk/

```
var pressTimer;
var $result = $('#result');

$("#area").mouseup(function () {
    clearInterval(pressTimer)
    // Clear timeout
    return false;
}).mousedown(function () {
    // Set timeout
    pressTimer = window.setInterval(function () {
        $result.text($result.text() + 'yay!');
    }, 1000)
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `setInterval` inside your `setTimeout` and use `clearInterval` to stop.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it is seeking

http://jsfiddle.net/Ze3FH/

```
var pressTimer;
        $("#area").mouseup(function () {
            clearInterval(pressTimer)
            // Clear timeout
            return false;
        }).mousedown(function(){
            // Set timeout
            pressTimer = window.setInterval(function () {
                $('#result').html($('#result').html() + 'yay!');
                alert("2");
            }, 1000);                
            return false; 
        });
```